# prevent form submission

Tags: php, validation

Say in my cms I have a few page that only internal personnel could go to that page and submit sensitive information... how do I prevent from people fake a form to submit from that page?

Assuming they could try to recreate the form with guessed input name and they are in the same domain (a public page contain form and they change from there)

Comment: Once the form is submitted, validate that the user who submitted has the permission to do so...

Comment: @Simon thanks did not think about that !! is there anymore others way to prevent proof?? just want to make sure the form is in most security as possible

Comment: How do you secure the forms themselves, and why do you think that the same technique is insufficient or unavailable for the URLs which process the form input?

Comment: Have you looked at OWASP site? They typically provide approaches and boilerplate code for these scenarios.

Comment: Andrew: That is normally achieved by using "sessions". Once a user logins, you create a session which you can easily validate on private pages.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments and effort guys !! indeed, session is the only true protection !! really thanks you guys !! @Simon if you put it into answer, I will be glad to take your answer and upvoted it :)

Answer (score 1):

Current Session can be checked with any request, so implement user privileges and check if current user has the required privillage to do the operation. Also make sure prpoper csrf protection is given to that form